# Dynamically Adding Object - Only Working Once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with dynamically embedding PDFs in IE8.

I have a div that I populate with a PDF on click of an element.
It works fine for the first click of any item, the pdf gets displayed.
But on on subsequent clicks I get nothing.

I am sure that the PDF url is being returned (I have alerted it out).

Some code;

The html;

```
<div id="pdf-preview-holder">

</div>
```

The jquery;

```
$('#table tbody tr').live('click', function() {
    var pdf_id = $(this).metadata().id;

    $.ajax({
        url: '/pdfs/get-pdf',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'id='+pdf_id,
        success: function( data ) {
        // pdf_path is an absolute url
        var pdf_path = data.pdf;
            $('#pdf-preview-holder').find('object').remove();
            $('<object id="pdf-preview" data="'+pdf_path+'" type="application/pdf" width="500" height="300" standby="Loading pdf..."><param name="src" value="'+pdf_path+'"></param><div class="err-text">Preview not available.<br />It appears that you do not have Adobe Reader of PDF support in this web browser.<br /><a id="asset-preview-alt" href="'+pdf_path+'" title="Download PDF" target="_blank">Click here to download the PDF</a></div></object>').appendTo('#pdf-preview-holder');
        },
        error: function( data ) {
            alert('oops, no PDF');
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**:: I have tested it by swapping the `<object>` for a `<p>` with some text and it works fine - it is definaltey something about the object tag it does not like.

Comment: Tested and works fine in Firefox, Chrome, IE9, Safari - just not IE8 (am NOT touching IE7!!)